# SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and excel 2013, some rows have misplaced columns

Tags: sql-server, excel

When I copy results with headers in SQL Server 2014 and paste into Excel 2013, save results as, or even just ctrl+c and ctrl+v into Excel, some rows will be split into two rows, when they should only be one.

**Database Entry**

```
colA        colB               colC
------------------------------------
1           hello 'return'ay   test
2           test1              test
```

Excel paste from 2008:

```
colA        colB               colC
------------------------------------
1           hello ay           test
2           test1              test
```

Excel paste from 2014:

```
colA        colB               colC
------------------------------------
1           hello 
ay          test
2           test1              test
```

I've found that it's most likely caused by users entering a 'return' key press on the front-end which is fine. If I use SQL Server 2008, they all stay within the same row.

Is there an option to allow SQL Server 2014 to act like SQL Server 2008 when coming across a 'return' in a single column?

**Edit:**
Is there a solution that doesn't involve me writing sql commands replacing every output column's tabs and carriage returns? Or going over every table's columns? This is viable for the project I'm working on now but to do this for every procedure already made and any future projects would be a HUGE project in itself.

Comment: use a REPLACE() on char13 and char10. (replace tabs and carriage returns with a space if it won't affect the data).  Excel loves to delimit by tabs when you paste data in.

Comment: right click in excel and paste special?

Comment: @xQbert Paste special as text or unicode doesn't work. Just tried it.  Looks like the replace is the only solution so far but I don't want to do this for every every solution, as this is quite a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing Tabs and Carriage Returns with spaces in your results.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(colA,CHAR(13),' '),CHAR(9),' ') AS 'colA'
    , REPLACE(REPLACE(colB,CHAR(13),' '),CHAR(9),' ') AS 'colB'
    , REPLACE(REPLACE(colC,CHAR(13),' '),CHAR(9),' ') AS 'colC'
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Carriage returns (13) and Line feeds (10) are the usual culprits as you suspect, slight alteration to @EMUEVIL solution

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(colA,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'') AS 'colA'
    , REPLACE(REPLACE(colB,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'') AS 'colB'
    , REPLACE(REPLACE(colC,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'') AS 'colC'
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I downloaded and installed sql server management studio 2016

[SQL server management studio 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt238290.aspx)

Under Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid
There is a checkbox that says Retain CR/LF on copy or save, make sure that is checked.

All grid results should be fine now for excel.

Comment: Interesting; I have tried this option in the past with no joy. Just re-tested and it still doesn't work for me. I used a few ApexSQL plugins so not sure if that's interfering.